# Table not sitting within the a div correctly

Tags: css, safari

There is a table on the bottom left of this screen which fits within each tab when you click on it.

It works ok in FF & IE but for some reason Safari pushes it out to the right.

http://www.yellostudio.co.uk/tm/#

Any ideas would be very much appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion, your HTML [doesn't validate](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.yellostudio.co.uk/tm/&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0), especially with regard to `<tr>` elements, this could be your problem.

To be fair, even if it isn't the problem getting your HTML valid is generally a good thing :-)

Comment: missed closing </tr> Thanks didnt notice it

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just need to change this

```
div.panes div { display:none; width:208px;}
```

to this

```
div.panes div { display:none; width:208px; float:left; }
```